# If Query Didn't Find Any Match

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a webpage that creates a cookie in client's computer named "token" with a random value inside when he is logging in. That cookie is created from a separate login page and not included here as the cookie is already getting created without problems.

Then I match the cookie token's value from the client's computer with the token value I have in the SQLite3 database. If both matches, I select the email of the client from the same row as the token.

Currently this method works if the cookie token's value and the database token matches as expected. But I'm having trouble figuring out the way if both tokens didn't match, so there would be no email to show. To be exact I have the problem around;

```
if(!$email)
```

area of the code because I don't know how to check if there's no email to return.

Here is the entire code that I have, please note that variables like `$url` and `$db` are already passed from external `*.php` files that I have included.

```
<?php include 'root.php';?>
<?php include ''.$root.'/database.php';?>

<?php

$token=$_COOKIE["token"];   
$auth = $db->query("select email, token from users where token='$token'");

if(!isset($token)){
    header('location: '.$url.'/login');
}
else {
    while ($row = $auth->fetchArray()){
        $email=$row['email'];
        if(!$email){
            echo "Didn't find any emails matching with the current cookie.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution can be:

```
$token = $_COOKIE["token"];
// Why execute a query if token is not set?
if(!isset($token)){
    header('location: '.$url.'/login');
    exit();
}

$auth = $db->query("select email, token from users where token='$token'");
// `fetchArray` fetches you row of FALSE if there are no rows.
$row = $auth->fetchArray();

if ($row) {
    $email=$row['email'];
} else {
    echo "Didn't find any emails matching with the current cookie.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `fetchArray()` method returns a result, `$row` will always be a truthy value. You can instead check if the `$row` value is truthy, as a query that returned no result, would make `fetchArray()` return `false`. You also check if a variable *you previously defined* is set. You should check if the cookie is set instead, and `exit` after the `header()` call. You also don't need to go in and out of PHP like that, unless doing something that is not parseable in PHP-

```
<?php 
include 'root.php';
include $root.'/database.php';

if (!isset($_COOKIE["token"])) {
    header('location: '.$url.'/login');
    exit;
}

$token = $_COOKIE["token"];   
$auth = $db->query("SELECT email, token as cnt FROM users WHERE token='$token'");
$row = $auth->fetchArray();

if ($row) {
    // Email exists! Use $row['email'] and $row['token']
} else {
    // No rows matching the condition
}
```

- [`fetchArray()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php)